# Discord.py: has_permissons() not working -- error is not an instance of MissingPermissions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to implement a discord command where if a user with **`manage_roles`** permission types `!add_country UAE` , the bot appends the args (ie. UAE) to a text file. Everything seems to be working except the error handler in case **`manage_roles`** permission is missing.

```
from discord.ext import commands

from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions


@bot.command(name = "add_country", pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True)  
async def add_country(ctx, arg):
    with open('countries.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f"""\n{arg}""")
    await ctx.channel.send(f"""Added {arg} to the list of countries""")

@add_country.error
async def add_country_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to do that!")

    else:
        print("Not an instance")
```

The output, when a user without permissions send the command, **`Not an instance`** gets printed out. So I can clearly conclude that something is wrong with the isinstance() function. It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `add_country_error(error, ctx)` `ctx` should be the first argument.

Comment: @TinNguyen Solved. Thank you! that was a very silly mistake